# Does Management Studio let me change the format of new script names?

Tags: ssms

I use SQL Server Mangagement Studio to examine the definition of objects in my database.

For example, to examine the definition of the table dbo.MSreplication_options in the master database, I would right-click on the table in the Object Explorer and choose 'Script Table as... > CREATE to > New Query Editor Window...'.

[image: Lots of genericly-named query scripts. What might they contain?]

As you can see from the screenshot of the current state of my Management Studio, a new tab is created for a new script called "SQLQuery9.sql", which contains the table definition.

By this time I have already examined a few other objects in this way, and have forgotten what most of the other scripts called "SQLQuery1.sql", "SQLQuery2.sql" and so on contain.

How can I configure management studio give the script a more descriptive name, perhaps containing the name of the object, like "dbo.MSreplication_options.sql", for example.

My Management Studio version is 10.0.5500.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

The SSMS tab is named after the open file, not the contents of the window/file.
So if you have not saved it, it has no name to assign

Comment: I don't understand your second statement. The table is named by a `CREATE TABLE` statement. Did you mean 'tab'? Is there no way to set the pattern by which Management Studio names the new files it creates?

Comment: Nope, there's no pattern of names there. Every time is just a SQLQueryxx.sql

Comment: @isme: yes, I meant tab

Comment: My co-worker was sure this feature exists, or used to, but we couldn't find it anywhere in the options menu. Is there perhaps a plugin that provides the functionality?

Comment: @isme: no plugin that that I know of.